# When email arrives (V3) wont trigger in different resource group

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-manager

I have a logic app with a trigger "when an email arrives (v3)" that is firing in one resource group but not the other. The deployment is automated and the code is the same on both environments.

I just can't work out why it triggers in one resource group but not the other, I've even pointed them to the same mailbox and same outcome. The resource group where it doesn't run I need to manually trigger it and then it will pull in the new email.

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get the logic app trigger working:

- Deleted the trigger & all actions from the logic app
- Saved the empty logic app
- Ran the pipeline again to deploy the Logic App

I've made no code changes to the template or any of the connections but it started working as expected.

I'm guessing that when its deploying to a new environment and creating the new o365 connection, it's unauthorised during deployment which might be affecting the trigger for "When a new email arrives". Recreating the logic app once the connection already exists seems to have worked for me.